Padding cannot understood
I have AES CBC 128 bit code in hex (each 2 character is one byte in hexadecimal representation).
56F2EFE1302C86FDB537346BAD697713FE6560E1B98696D9E28389FCFE3F4202B14247764A89D97FC0E5134CD08AC4E34BF7

My initial vector and key are 128 bits also in hex representation like above:
KEY: 00000000000000000000000000000000
IV:  01069867650300000000000000000000

Each 128 bit section of code is:
56F2EFE1302C86FDB537346BAD697713
FE6560E1B98696D9E28389FCFE3F4202
B14247764A89D97FC0E5134CD08AC4E3
4BF7

For top three section decrypted values (in hex) are:
2F2F0FD805DA9D0E646625C462E65CF3
153A951501010000106F0400007B014C
0400005A0300003B0200003F01000076

But cannot decrypt last section contained two bytes. I know that decrypted values should be 0x00 0x00 however cannot achieve it, getting some values different than zero.
Where I made a mistake?  How properly use padding in my example for last section?
BR, Krzysiek

If it is CBC and the size of the ciphertext is different from a number of times the block size then probably cipher text stealing is used. That also means that you've probably already decrypted the 00 00 bytes. The problem: there are 3 different versions of CTS and implementations are not common.

Thank you for an answer . I found article on wiki about the topic:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing
however is too complex to me for implement in my excel solution....

Meh, just ask ChatGPT to implement it in VBA :P
